# .NET MAUI XAML: How to make a CollectionView/ListView correctly convert and display null values?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I have a ViewModel with the following property:

```
    [ObservableProperty]
    ObservableCollection<Agent> agentList;
```

This collection is databound to the the ItemSource of a CollectionView and I'm using AgentToStringConverter to display Agent objects. This converter returns the string "None" if the value is null, however "None" is not showing up on my UI when AgentList contains a null value.

```
                    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding AgentList}"
                                    SelectionMode="Multiple"
                                    SelectedItems="{Binding QueryAgents}"
                                    IsVisible="{Binding EnableFilters}"
                                    Grid.Row="2"
                                    Grid.Column="3">
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Label Text="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource AgentToString}}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>
```

This is the converter:

```
internal class AgentToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    // Property to get Agents collection from, set in Resource declaration of ProjectDetailsPage.xaml
    public SettingsViewModel SettingsViewModel { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Agent agent)
        {
            var percentage = agent.FeeDecimal * 100;
            return $"{agent.Name}: {percentage:F1}%";
        }

        else if (value == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("NULL VALUE CONVERTED");
            return "None";
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string stringValue)
        {
            // Split the string into parts assuming it's in the format: "Name: Percentage%"
            var parts = stringValue.Split(':');

            if (parts.Length == 2 && decimal.TryParse(parts[1].Trim().TrimEnd('%'), out decimal percentage))
            {
                var name = parts[0].Trim();
                var feeDecimal = percentage / 100.0m;
                var agent = SettingsViewModel.Agents.First(a => a.Name == name && a.FeeDecimal == feeDecimal);
                return agent;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

For testing purposes I have also used the same AgentList and AgentToStringConverter for a Picker and a ListView.

```
                    <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding AgentList}"
                            ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource AgentToString}}"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="3" />

                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AgentList}"
                              IsVisible="{Binding EnableFilters}"
                              Grid.Row="1"
                              Grid.Column="3">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource AgentToString}}" />
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>

                    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding AgentList}"
                                    SelectionMode="Multiple"
                                    SelectedItems="{Binding QueryAgents}"
                                    IsVisible="{Binding EnableFilters}"
                                    Grid.Row="2"
                                    Grid.Column="3">
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Label Text="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource AgentToString}}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>
```

The UI correctly displays "None" as a picker option, the ListView displays an empty space, and the CollectionView completely skips the null value and only shows the not-null Agents.
Is there any way I can make the CollectionView or the ListView display the "None" for null values?

This is my collection [i.imgur.com/MB0ix7F.png](https://i.imgur.com/MB0ix7F.png)

And this is how it's displayed as Picker options on the left, and as a CollectionView on the right: [i.imgur.com/Qg2aK7j.png](https://i.imgur.com/Qg2aK7j.png)

Both using the same AgentList as ItemSource and AgentToStringConverter as converter.

Comment: Have you tried testing for NULL first?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what that is supposed to achieve. I will always have a null value in my collection and I want to display it as "None" on the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no nulls here:

```
[ObservableProperty]
ObservableCollection<Agent> agentList;
```

ObservableCollection is observable enough. No need to create field, then property.

You can do something like:

```
 class AgentWrapper {
       Agent agent; //this gets set null every now and then
 }
```

And then make `ObservableCollection< AgentWrapper >`. Again - no nulls here, just inside.

Edit: Another alternative:

```
public String Property;

public String DisplayProperty
{
      get { return Property == null?"None":Property; }
}
```

And we bind to:

```
<Label Text="{Binding DisplayProperty}" />
```

Comment: Good point about ObservableCollection being observable enough. And creating a wrapper sounds like a good idea to get around the issue. I guess the results of null conversions not being properly displayed are just .NET MAUI CollectionView and ListView quirks? Because the AgentToStringConverter.Convert method is being called for the null values, but then nothing is done with the resulting string it seems.

Comment: @sdhuys Show me a watch with your collection and added nulls to it. ( I want debug information, about AgentList content, right before it gets displayed in the list )

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/MB0ix7F.png

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Qg2aK7j.png

And this is my CollectionView on the left, and the Picker on the right. Both using the same AgentList as ItemSource and using the same AgentToStringConverter.

Comment: @sdhuys The converter is firing like crazy.

Comment: @sdhuys sorry man, I cannot do more before updating. To test with the newest version, I have to update, and when I update, I am risking to break something really important, and then have to deal with rollbacks. I will continue when I get to my not-that-important-pc.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, I ended up just using the wrapper class and that circumvented the issue.